# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many how to

Tags: php, relationship, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to learn Laravel and right now I'm experimenting with Eloquent.
I've got the following case that I can't solve right now:

Let's say I'm creating a webshop, so I have products (Product 1, Product 2, etc):

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| price       | decimal(5,2)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| active      | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Those products are sorted into Taxonomies (Brand, Color, Department):

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

These taxonomies have terms (Nike, Adidas, Red, Green, Boys, Girls):

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| taxonomy_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

And last I have a pivot table to connect the terms to the products:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| term_id    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I've created models for Product, Taxonomy and Term like this:

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function terms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Term', 'product_terms', 'product_id', 'term_id');
    }

}

<?php

class Taxonomy extends Eloquent {

    public function terms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Term');
    }

}

<?php

class Term extends Eloquent {

    public function taxonomy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Taxonomy');
    }

}
```

Now I want to do the following, I want to get all the products, loop over them and show something like the name, description and price.
Well, a simple `$products = Product::all();` is all I need. 
Then, when I loop over the products, I know I can do something like `$product->terms` to get all the terms. But how should a get the term of a given taxonomy. So for example something like this:

```
<?php
echo $product->term('brand'); // Where 'brand' is the taxonomy name of the term I want to get
echo $product->term('color'); // Where 'color' is the taxonomy name of the term I want to get
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I *think* I understand your setup. Given the relations you stated, I think you'd define your models as follows:

```
<?php

class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function terms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Term')->withTimestamps();
    }

}

<?php

class Taxonomy extends Eloquent {

    public function terms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Term');
    }

}

<?php

class Term extends Eloquent {

    public function taxonomy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Taxonomy');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Since your pivot is named and id'd correctly you shouldn't have to specify that info in the belongsToMany relationship, but if you want the timestamps to work you need the withTimestamps.

**EDIT:**

If you can look taxonomies up by id instead of slug, this will work:

```
$products = Product::all();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $term = $product->terms()->with('taxonomy')->where('taxonomy_id', '=', 2)->first();
    echo $term->name;
}
```

In the scenario above you could just store the taxonomy slug in the term table since it should be a unique key. Otherwise you could look over the terms and look for the one with the taxonomy that you want:

```
$products = Product::all();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    $terms = $product->terms()->with('taxonomy')->get();
    foreach($terms as $term)
    {
        if($term->taxonomy->slug == 'brand')
        {
            echo $term->name."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

**END EDIT**

I have to admit that I'm a little lost though because your last two tables seem exactly the same and I'm wondering why you associate terms with products instead of taxonomies with products. I'm suspect that my solution won't work with the way you're relating things but if you related taxonomies with products instead it would work jut fine.

```
<?php
$product->taxonomy()->where('slug', '=', 'brand')->term;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm going to have a look at it later today. But just a quick clear up, why I have terms related to products. A taxonomy is just a name for a set of terms. you have terms like 'Red, blue, green, yellow' and the taxonomy of those terms is 'Color'. For a product I want to get the "terms" it has. Not the taxonomies it has. Because typically, a product will have all taxonomies. I'm interested in which terms of a given taxonomy it has. "What color is the product", "What brand is the product"

Comment: Ow, and btw, the last two tables where indeed the same, but this was a mistake, Updated it right away.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Get this error:
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::taxonomy()`

Comment: Right, each product has a bunch of taxonomies and each taxonomy has a term. Because you want to know things like "What color is the product", you want to associate taxonomies with products instead of terms. Out of curiosity, does it work if you remove the parentheses? $product->terms->taxonomy()->where('slug', '=', 'brand')->first(); or $product->terms()->taxonomy->where('slug', '=', 'brand')->first(); or $product->terms->taxonomy->where('slug', '=', 'brand')->first(); or take the first off of the end.

Comment: Yeah, but if I would associate a product with a taxonomy. How would I get to know the term? I would ask "Which taxonomies does Product 1 have" and I would get "color, brands, department, etc." Not "red, Nike, Ladies"
Removing parentheses gives me the same kind of errors, only this time it's about an undefined relationship:
`Notice: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$taxonomy`

Comment: I'd think you'd just be able to do something like foreach($product->taxonomies as $taxonomy) { echo $taxonomy->term->name; } A shoe doesn't have "red" it is a color, which may be red. Also, something looks fishy about the "$taxonomy" part of that error, perhaps there's a bug in your class definition.

Comment: I meant it "has" a color, not it "is" a color. Red is obviously a color. Does: $taxonomy = $product->term('brand')->with('taxonomy'); echo $taxonomy->name; Work?

Comment: Just to be clear, what is $product in your eyes? the result of a foreach loop looping over all products returned by `$products = Product::all();`, so like `foreach($product as $product) { // your code }`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27697/discussion-between-crinsane-and-beau)